# Query on inherited entity framework class does not work

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

When I do the query:

```
Users.OfType<Student>().Where(u => u.StudentClasses.Any(sc => sc.Class.TermId == 1 && sc.Class.SubFormId == 1))
```

I get nothing. But this query returns true:

```
StudentClasses.Any(sc => sc.Class.TermId == 1 && sc.Class.SubFormId == 1)
```

So basically this is the same as:

```
Users.OfType<Student>().Where(u => true)
```

Which returns all the students. So `OfType<Student>` works.

I'm 100% sure that there are students in these classes `StudentClasses` but for some reason I get back no student although the subquery returns true.

`Student` is inherited from `User`, but only `Student` has `StudendClass`. What would be wrong with this query?

I basically want students in a particular subform/term (all these properties are in a `Class`.

I'm using Table per heirachy. Model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Map<Teacher>(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Teach"))
            .Map<Student>(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Stu"))
            .Map<Staff>(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Staff"));
```

Edit:

This also returns nothing:

```
Users.OfType<Student>().Where(u => u.StudentClasses.Any(sc => true))
```

Comment: Did you check the SQL generated by EF? Can't you use `User.Where(....`?

Comment: @Eranga cant, Student is inherited thus `StudentClasses` is not part of `User`. `User` is the base class.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was `Students.Where(....`?

Comment: @Eranga because students is not a part of the dbset, just user. I have to use OfType to get students or other inherited objects

Comment: Then how about `context.Set<Student>().Where(....`? :)

Comment: Are you using Table per type, Table per hierarchy, or Table per concrete class in the db? Have you checked SQL Analyzer to see what query is being sent to the db?

Comment: "*But this query returns true*": Did you test this for *all* users in the database or what does this mean? Only if the query on `StudentClasses` returns `true` for *all* users it is the same as `.Where(u => true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm 100% sure that there are students in these classes StudentClasses.

I am 99% sure there aren't. (1% for the potential case you have discovered some serious EF bug.) If there are students in classes with `Class.TermId == 1` and `Class.SubFormId == 1` your query must return those students.

Your test query...

```
(context.)StudentClasses.Any(sc => sc.Class.TermId == 1 && sc.Class.SubFormId == 1)
```

...has nothing to do with your original query. It only says that there is at least one row in the `StudentClasses` table with `Class.TermId == 1` and `Class.SubFormId == 1`.

It doesn't prove that you have any student which is in this particular class (or in these particular classes if there is more than one class with `Class.TermId == 1` and `Class.SubFormId == 1`). All your students could be in the other classes and your original query would correctly return no student as result. So, this is by no means identical with `(context.)Users.OfType<Student>().Where(u => true)`.

If you are still 100% sure you should show the content of your tables in a small example to make the problem reproducable for us.

Comment: I was using my own foreign key while EF generated one for me so the student wasn't actually related to any class. I fixed it by setting it up in the modelbuilder. I had `UserId` and EF gave me `Class_UserId`